# Windows Phone 8.1 Writing to File Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing text to a file in Windows Phone 8.1 like this:

```
private static async Task WriteData(String fileName, String content)
{
    Byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

But when I read the file, it comes back empty. I have verified that there isn't some other method overwriting it by reading from the file immediately after I write to it. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: even though you do have a using clause, have you tried to explicitly close the file aftet writing? i.e s.Close(); ? are you sure you are looking in the correct path for the folder? (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
public async Task SaveStreamToFile(Stream streamToSave, string fileName, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    Byte[] buf= Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (Stream fileStram = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {    
        int bytesread = 0;
        while ((bytesread = await streamToSave.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            await fileStram.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytesread);
            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I save 2 files, one with debug information, and one with application specific information (a list of routes).The debug information seems to work OK

```
StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await local.CreateFileAsync "debug.txt",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, sbDebugInformation.ToString());
```

but the CreateCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting seemed to be causing problems with the other information, and I ended up with this, after many alternate attempts

```
StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RouteList));
var file = await local.CreateFileAsync(filename,CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
json.WriteObject(stream, routes);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, stream.ToArray());
```